# Does anyone have suggestions for how Goodfellow et al detected digits from the larger Street View images in their 2014 paper?

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection

In their 2014 paper titled, "[Multi-digit Number Recognition from Street View Imagery using Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/42241.pdf)", they write,

> We use an automated method (beyond the scope of this paper) to
>   estimate the centroid of each house number, then crop to a 128 × 128
>   pixel region surrounding the house number.

Can anyone suggest possible methods they used to accomplish this task?